# Unwind does not show all data

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I have a collection which looks like this:

```
{

  "consultation_type" : "1",
  "encounter_id" : "12345"
}
```

I am applying the following query:

```
db.encounter.aggregate([{ "$unwind" : "$vitals"},{ "$match" : { "$eq" : [ "$vitals.spirometer.FVC" , "null"]}},{$limit:1}])
```

but I don't get any result. Is there something wrong in my query?

Comment: I add to fix your document, as you missed the } for "test".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your aggregate command, I get the error:

> Mon Aug 12 10:01:01.269 JavaScript execution failed: aggregate failed: {
>     "errmsg" : "exception: bad query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $eq",

You shouldn't need `$eq`, but instead do:

```
db.encounter.aggregate( [
    { "$unwind" : "$vitals" },
    { "$match" : { "vitals.spirometer.FVC" : "null" } },
    { $limit : 1 }
] )
```

`$eq` is only used for in conditions.

Comment: In that case how can I implement not equal ("$neq")

Comment: Just like with any other find query: ``{ "vitals.spirometer.FVC" : { $neq: "null" } }``